# How to prevent entering more value when I press enter using keydown event

Tags: javascript, events

Sorry in advance if I'm not making any sense.  I'm a complete beginner to coding.  I'm creating a shopping list and a user will enter the items through placeholder and will click or press enter to add the items in the list.

The click event is working properly.

Edit

[image]

```js
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (input.value.length > 0) {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
        ul.appendChild(li);
        input.value = "";
    }
})

document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    if (input.value.length > 0, event.key === 'Enter') {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
        ul.appendChild(li);
        input.value = "";
    }
  });
```

```html
<input type='text' id='userinput' />
<button type='button' id='enter'>Enter</button>

<ul></ul>
```

Comment: Hey, could you elaborate more on your issue please ?

Comment: This is working for me, but your condition is incorrect, you'll want a [logical AND(&&)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND). `if (input.value.length > 0 && event.key === 'Enter') {`

Comment: @pilchard I forgot to comment back.  But that was the main issue of my code.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can you elaborate more on your question?
Also, stick to the "DRY" principle. You have both the button and the input adding a item then adding it to the list:
Make a function that takes the input and call it on both the button and the input event:

```
function addListItem(input){
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
    ul.appendChild(li);
    input.value = "";
};
```

It'll look like this:

```
        button.addEventListener("click", function() {
        if (input.value.length > 0) {
            AddListItem(input);
        }
    });
    input.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
        if (input.value.length > 0 &&  event.key === 'Enter') {
            AddListItem(input);
        }
      });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I'm just following along with a course video and need to be updated (still using keyCode and keypress, which are both deprecated) hence I tried to find an alternative on my own.

Answer (score 0):

//  So, If I'm getting it correct. You have an input field and you're //reading values from that field
//  So add 'keyup' to input element.
// Fix the IF
// control the input length in order to control values?

I need more info on this: How to prevent entering more value when I press enter using keydown event

```
        var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
        var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
        var btn = document.querySelector('#enter')
        
        btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
            if (input.value.length > 0) {
                var li = document.createElement("li");
                li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
                ul.appendChild(li);
                input.value = "";
            }
        })
        
        input.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
            //basically, if the input value is falsy('') you return nothing or false (abort)
            if(!input.value) {
                return;
                //return false;
                //alert('cannot add empty list item')
              }

            if (input.value.length > 0 &&  event.key === 'Enter') {
                var li = document.createElement("li");
                li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
                ul.appendChild(li);
                input.value = "";
            }
          });
```

Comment: please refer to the screenshot I recently added.

Comment: Also follow @Mike0608 's advice.  2 different listeners achieving the same thing. you might wanna handle that function in one place...